# How can I update info in MySQL without setting a specific Where variable?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an Android app for class and am having trouble updating profile information in my database.

This is the php code I use that uploads the user data to a table in my database.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("database", "host", "username", "password");

$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$bio = $_POST["bio"];
$university = $_POST["university"];
$illness = $_POST["illness"];
$symptoms = $_POST["symptoms"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, username, password, bio, university, illness, symptoms) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssssssss", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $username, $password, $bio, $university, $illness, $symptoms);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response); ?>
```

After the user enters their data, it us uploaded and they are taken to their profile screen. On the profile screen there is a button that when clicked takes them to a form to update all of the profile information that was just inserted.

I guess my question is I am not sure how to set this php up to edit a specific row in the database because the unique ID is auto incremented and I can't just set the php to go to a specific ID value to update that row because all user's ID will be different.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The database is MySQL. phpMyAdmin is simply a web app that let's you manage it.

Comment: parse the id in the url or a session

Answer (score -1):

I'd highly suggest taking Code Academy's MySQL tutorial. It'll show you how to query data, and how you modify/destroy it.

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sql